# How to get data from api on html view using node js?

Tags: node.js

```
var Request = require("request");

Request.get("https://www.yonline.com", (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML=JSON.parse(body)
    console.dir(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

I tried this code, but it is only giving data on the command line. i want it to give data on the intended textfield.

Comment: I don't know where are you testing this code, if this is in browser environment, I think axios package is a better choice than request. I don't think request is built to be used in browser.

Answer (score -1):

NodeJS is server side script you can't access HTML element like this.
You need to do it on html javascript side.